# EXC_BAD_ACCESS on resume on iOS device with Intel XDK

Tags: ios, cordova, exc-bad-access, intel-xdk, phaser-framework

I'm making a iOS game using the Intel XDK, but when the game is suspended and resume , it crashed with an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error (on iphone5,iOS 8.4.1).

I saw here : http://www.christian-cook.co.uk/ how to debug and fix it, but I don't know how to do without to use Xcode.

is it possible with intel XDK to "Enable Zombie Objects" ? and how overwrite "MainViewController.m" for disable animations on the UIView ?

config : 
HTML5+Cordova project ( game engine Phaser)
cordova cli version 5.1.1
ios target version 8
I deleted all the plugins
no web sockets.

(sorry my english isn't very good)
Thanks !

Comment: use xcode, intel xdk should create an xcode project to run the app, search for that project and open it

Comment: thanks jcesarmobile , but finally this plugin https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/WKWebView fix this issue